# Refresing a SWF loaded in a c# windows form

Tags: c#, actionscript-3

I'm using an AxShockwaveFlash object in C# to load and display a SWF inside of a Windows form.

I'm loading it using LoadMovie and everything is working fine

```
axShockwaveFlash.LoadMovie(0, "local url");
```

For debugging reasons I want to be able to refresh this swf without having to rebuild the c# application.

I've tried a couple of things including loading a blank swf before reloading the real one.

```
axShockwaveFlash.LoadMovie(0, "");
axShockwaveFlash.LoadMovie(0, "local url");
```

However this does not seem to work.

Does anyone happen to know how I can reload the axShockwaveFlash object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah was able to figure that out pretty quickly. It seems like creating a loading a blank swf does the trick.

```
axShockwaveFlash.LoadMovie(0, "EmptySwf.swf");
axShockwaveFlash.LoadMovie(0, "RealProjectSwf.swf");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also let it load a video from youtube and then right after it load your SWF or whatever you want like so :

```
        string tmpStr = axShockwaveFlash1.Movie;

        axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, "http://www.youtube.com/v/jNQXAC9IVRw");
        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();

        axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, tmpStr);
        axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```